# As per checking vs as per check

Tags: word-usage, sentence

I always start my email with **"As per checking,......"** but I found out there is someone else who used to write **"As per check,..."**.

Sentence example :

> **As per checking**, we found out the issue was caused from our side.

In this case, is my sentence wrong? Should I change to check/checked instead? But *checking* sounds a lot more suitable than *check*.

Comment: As the answer below says, neither variant works because you can't use "as per" there. To that I will add that the whole introductory phrase is probably needless clutter that has no point being there in the first place. You are already saying that you *found* what caused the issue. That alone is perfectly sufficient to imply that you went and checked what caused it.

Comment: I can't resist showing part of an [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=As%20Per) post: << **as per**  [top definition] 
With the intended meaning of "according to", this is a popular nonsense phrase used by people trying to sound smart and technical. >>  (It's not a fair quote; I don't like the rest of it, so I've omitted it.) (Also, 'as per' has a legitimate but very technical/formal use. But 'as per [our] check/s/ing' for 'when we compare with our records' would be better 'on checking' or even, more humbly, 'when we checked'.

Comment: Unless this is about an issue with your checking account, neither version makes much sense.

Comment: Keep the asperdestra flying.

Comment: I agree with @RegDwigнt about definitely deleting "As per" and probably deleting "checking". I'll add the suggestion to also delete "we found out" and just say "The issue was caused from our side." (I'd probably write "Sorry, that was our fault", but I suppose you need to be more formal than that.)

Comment: @RegDwigнt agreed. Removing the "as per" on the beginning of a sentence would sound more suitable, as it means that I've already went on checking. Can you post your answers to the forum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"As per" is a preposition, meaning according to/in accordance with. 'As per checking' does not sound natural to me. I'd rather use "upon checking."

Comment: I find "As per checking,......" as an invariable start to an email to be unidiomatic in British and American English, and pretty much meaningless. But, for all I know, it may be acceptable in Subcontinental English. How do your emails continue, and what does the phrase mean?

Comment: @Greybeard The emails go on with the solution that we made on the issue. For example, "We have removed the parts from the settings and it is good to go." Anyhow, I agree to remove the "as per" from the sentence.